# How to get RegEx to distinguish expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I hope the title of the question makes sense.

I had to revise a webscraper to add VIEWSTATEGENERATOR. This is the code I am using to get the VIEWSTATE

```
var viewState = Regex.Match(
    responsedata, 
    "__VIEWSTATE.+?value=\"(.+?)\"",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
```

This worked fine for scraping all the records, but now since the want to refine the scrape function I have noticed that there is also a VIEWSTATEGENERATOR field.

I don't know how to get Regex to differentiate between the two. I need to still get the ViewState, and now VIEWSTATEGENERATOR.
I have limited experience with RegEx but I know by looking at the code and it can't distinguish between the two and now I never get the ViewState, just the VIEWSTATEGENERATOR value.

**SAMPLE**
[image: This is a screen shot from Fiddler2, You can see that there is VIEWSTATE and VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]

Here is the string, this is where my expression is not working because it sees the viewstate and viewstategenerator and I need to separate the two.

> manScript_HiddenField=&__EVENTTARGET=p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24btnSubmit&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&lng=en-CA&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=A5343185&p%24lt%24ctl00%24SearchBox%24txtWord=Site+Search&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24txtLastName=&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24grpGender=+&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddLanguage=08&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24grpDocType=rdoDocTypeSpecialist&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddSpecialist=149&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24grpStatus=rdoStatusActive&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddCity=Select+--%3E&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24txtPostalCode=&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddHospitalCity=Select+--%3E&p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddHospitalName=-1&__VIEWSTATE=%

Comment: Is a regex really the easiest way to do this?

Comment: @emodendroket, probably not, but it worked perfectly until I the VIEWSTATEGENERATOR came into play

Comment: Can you show a sample of what is the string you are trying to parse?

Comment: @Dzyann, sure, it will take a couple minutes then I'll edit the question and add a sample

Comment: `VIEWSTATE.+?` matches both VIEWSTATE and VIEWSTATEGENERATOR. Whats the problem ?

Comment: @sln, the problem is when I go to post the data from the response, I am only getting the value of VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and not VIEWSTATE

Comment: I need Regex to only get the "VIEWSTATE" and its value, and then grab the "VIEWGENERATOR" value, to go into separate strings

Comment: From your sample string, there is no VIEWSTATE though, right? The only VIEWSTATE has `%` as value. And there is no `value` word in this sample string. Could you perhaps give a proper sample string, the values you are currently getting and the values you would have liked to get instead? Maybe a few like this to highlight different cases maybe, if there are different scenarios?

Comment: @Jerry, I didn't add the VIEWSTATE value when I edited the question, there was way to much there. But there is a value following it, just didn't add it

Comment: Well, if your original regex worked, I posted a mod to it that will only get VIEWSTATE. It's more likely your original regex, does not work with the new target string. For instance, I don't see `value` anywhere in your test string. Also, you have to have the `Dot-All` modifier for your regex.

Comment: @sln the 'dot-all' is called 'Singleline' in C# :)

Comment: Its a misnomer Jerry, its dot-all. Oh, you mean the enum.

Comment: that's exactly the problem, its the "dot-all". And I don't know enough about Regex to fix it. The "dot-all" is for the VIEWSTATE and its encoded string, so when it sees the VIEWSTATE in VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, it automatically gives me that value and doesn't bother with the VIEWSTATE

Comment: Figured it out, I was doing things wrong. I also forgot to add the VIEWSTATEGENERATOR to my postData. Now its working.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean but, to ensure no `GENERATOR`

```
"__VIEWSTATE(?!GENERATOR).+?value=\"(.+?)\""
```